# How to put two array inside new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Please have a look over the result that currently i have now:

```
0: {
  tasks: 
    0: {CategoryId: "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2"}
    1: {CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"}
    2: {CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"}
} 
1: {
  tasks: 
    0: {CategoryId: "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", CategoryName: 
      "Category 2"}
    1: {CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: 
      "Category 1"}
    2: {CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: 
    "Category 1"}
}
2: {
    tasks: 
      0: {CategoryId: "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", CategoryName: 
      "Category 2"}
      1: {CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: 
      "Category 1"}
 }
```

Above is currently my result that is coming in loop, means total 3 result is coming in loop.

And inside every result you can see tasks is there, and in tasks also contain data in loop is coming.

Now, I want to combine all data of task and put in new array.

I want below result:

```
0: { 
  CategoryId: "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2"
  CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"
  CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"
}
1: { 
  CategoryId: "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2"
  CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"
  CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"}   
2: {
  CategoryId: "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2"
  CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"
}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: you can try array map function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself:

```
data.forEach(elementData => {
    if(elementData.tasks) {
      arrayFirst.push(elementData.tasks);
    }
  });
  arrayFirst.forEach(dataNext=>{
    if(dataNext) {
      dataNext.forEach(elementNext => {
        if(elementNext) {
          newArrayData.push(elementNext);
        }
      });
    }
  })
```

console.log(newArrayData)

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can have the result you are wanting (you cannot have 2 keys with same name in an object Eg: CategoryId

> 0: { 
>     CategoryId: "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2",
>     CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1",
>     CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"
>   }

)

what  you can do instead is following,
I assume your array is obj, and you are looping it somewhat like this,

```
var newArr = []
obj.forEach((ele,idx)=>{
    newArr.push(ele["tasks"])
})

console.log(newArr)
```

and get

`0 : [{
    CategoryId: '4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92',
    CategoryName: 'Category 2'
}, {
    CategoryId: 'ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c',
    CategoryName: 'Category 1'
}, {
    CategoryId: 'ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c',
    CategoryName: 'Category 1'
}]
1 : [{
    CategoryId: '4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92',
    CategoryName: 'Category 2'
}, {
    CategoryId: 'ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c',
    CategoryName: 'Category 1'
}, {
    CategoryId: 'ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c',
    CategoryName: 'Category 1'
}]
2 : [{
    CategoryId: '4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92',
    CategoryName: 'Category 2'
}, {
    CategoryId: 'ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c',
    CategoryName: 'Category 1'
}]`

```js
var json = `[{
  "tasks": 
    [{"CategoryId": "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", "CategoryName": "Category 2"},
    {"CategoryId": "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", "CategoryName": "Category 1"},
    {"CategoryId": "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", "CategoryName": "Category 1"}]
}, 
{
  "tasks": 
    [{"CategoryId": "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", "CategoryName":"Category 2"},
    {"CategoryId": "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", "CategoryName": "Category 1"},
    {"CategoryId": "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", "CategoryName":"Category 1"}]
},
{
"tasks":
      [{"CategoryId": "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", "CategoryName": "Category 2"},
      {"CategoryId": "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", "CategoryName": "Category 1"}]
}]`


var obj = JSON.parse(json)

var newArr = []
obj.forEach((ele,idx)=>{
  newArr.push(ele["tasks"])
})

newArr.forEach((element,idx)=>{

  console.log(idx,element)

})
```

Comment: Using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) would probably be simpler. Although it's not sure what the input and output should be since question has input that is not valid JS syntax and output that has duplicate keys in the object literal.

Answer (score 0):

Are these the correct formatted object data you are posting here? or if possible can you get properly formatted data from the loop?

```
   var result_field = { 0: {
0: {CategoryId: "4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2"},
1: {CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"},
2: {CategoryId: "ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1"},
```

} }

if yes then you can create another object variable using each loop in which you are looking the result.

```
each(result_field[0] , function( index, value ){ 
var new_field = //formate as per your requirement 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for this:

```js
const data = [{"tasks":[{"CategoryId":"4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92","CategoryName":"Category 2"},{"CategoryId":"ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c","CategoryName":"Category 1"},{"CategoryId":"ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c","CategoryName":"Category 1"}]},{"tasks":[{"CategoryId":"4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92","CategoryName":"Category 2"},{"CategoryId":"ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c","CategoryName":"Category 1"},{"CategoryId":"ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c","CategoryName":"Category 1"}]},{"tasks":[{"CategoryId":"4a6dcb18-94f6-4ef5-8ea8-9872cce5af92","CategoryName":"Category 2"},{"CategoryId":"ee3102c7-de53-48f7-90ca-b5c3f43f941c","CategoryName":"Category 1"}]}];

console.log(
  data.map((item) => item.tasks)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example setup of what I think you are trying to display:

```
    // These are the objects containing your data of each Category
    var data1 = {CategoryName: "Category 2", CategoryColor: "purple"};
    var data2 = {CategoryName: "Category 5", CategoryColor: "yellow"};
    var data3 = {CategoryName: "Category 2", CategoryColor: "blue"};

    // These are the arrays holding your category objects
    var array1 = [data1, data2];
    var array2 = [data1, data2];
    var array3 = [data3, data1];

    // The tasks property in the objects contain the arrays with the catergory objects in.
    var obj1 = {timeKey: "Wednesday", timeAgo: "2 days ago", tasks: array1};
    var obj2 = {timeKey: "Tuesday", timeAgo: "3 days ago", tasks: array2};
    var obj3 = {timeKey: "Monday", timeAgo: "4 days ago", tasks: array3};

    // The array displayed in your console
    var myArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
```

To put the tasks property values into a new array, you just move down into the object as far as you want to retrieve the data:

```
var newData = myArray[1]["tasks"] // this will select the array containing the Category objects.

var newArray = [];
newArray.push(newData);
```

If you want to select only one of the Object categories from within the array, go one step further:

```
var newData = myArray[1]["tasks"][0];
var newArray = [];
newArray.push(newData);
```

Test this in your console to navigate down the **myArray** array.